# SSRS Adding whitespace to right of fields

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, removing-whitespace

So I'm currently creating a report and whenever I render the report on CRM Dynamics it's adding a ton of whitespace to the right of every field like this:
[Bunch of white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZgBa.png)

What I've tried so far:

-Changing CanGrow to false (I'm aware that CanGrow only affects if it can grow vertically)

-Adding the table to a new report

-Setting ConsumeWhiteSpace to true

I've been looking for a way to make the table columns static but according to Microsoft's documentation, they should be static by default.

For reference here is how I want the report to look, this is the view I get when getting the preview in Visual Studios: [What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVxqq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the grey space outside of your report and go to properties. Make sure your report is in portrait mode and set your margins. With default margins of 1" your page width should be under 6.5". Drag the border of your page to the left until it is LESS than 6.5" (so you can't see the .5" hash mark). If you adjust your margins to be smaller you can make it a bit wider but I don't recommend less than .5" margins.

I think what is happening is your page is so large the tables are stretching to with the empty space.

Comment: It seems to be the opposite, the table is stretching the page, as when I remove the table the report looks correct.